# How to hash passwords in mysql for spring security compatibility

Tags: mysql, spring-security

I'm loading a lot of user profiles at once. I generate the SQL script for the mysql database using the `password()` function.
But this dosen't make it. The password generated is not the same one generated in spring boot application form.

This is for MySQL server 5.7.26 running on linux 4.15.0-54 and java 8

for example for the password string 'test0000', the spring security generated password is :
`5f7433f76544679849ec917c3baa70e0852b3d025fb52ecb7839c6fe911f75c49b3b2315aa3589c`
but with the password('test0000') function in mysql it gives : 
`*FED47FB319BAC61E726825628D8A5D22979E9F1C`

So how to generate the springboot like password on mysql or in the commandline in linux?

Comment: The solution may be a java console app

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's `password()` function uses `SHA1(SHA1(password))` to calculate hash.

The Spring Security uses `PasswordEncoder` interface to `encode` and `match` and has different implementations available to handle BCrypt, MD5, SHA256, etc.

So, for the passwords to be compatible on both ends, you need to use the same algorithm.

Since the hashing algorithms are slow, it is not advised to use these in the SQL.